# Change my Facebook Page's username/link more than once

Tags: facebook, username

How can I change my Facebook Page's username/link more than one time?

Answer (score 1):

**[You cannot](https://www.facebook.com/help/162586890471598).**

> You can only change the username for your personal profile once.

If you have a really, **really**, good reason you might try to [ask a question](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/ask/) on their support forum, but I wouldn't get my hopes up.